# How to distinguish bigrams and merge them into one CSV file in R Studio

Tags: r, csv, nlp, rstudio

Alright so I am trying to have R read sentences, pull out bigrams, and merge all of these bigrams together into one csv.  Right now I have the code to pull out bigrams for one sentence:

```
sentence=gsub('[[:punct:]]','', sentence)
    sentence=gsub('[[:cntrl:]]','', sentence)
    sentence=gsub('\\d+','', sentence)
    sentence=tolower(sentence)
    words<- strsplit(sentence, "\\s+")[[1]]
    New=NULL
    for(i in 1:length(words)-1){ 
      New[i]=paste(words[i],words[i+1])     
  }
New=as.matrix(New)
colnames(New)<-"Bigrams"
```

However, I want to be able to import a csv filled with different sentences and have the previous line of code pull out bigrams for each sentence and then merge them together into one csv file. I started writing a code (below) but it is not right.  I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.  Pretty new to natural language processing in R.

```
library(tm)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
data<-read.csv("file.csv")
sentences=as.vector(data$text)

bigrams<-function(sentences){

bigrams2<-mlply(sentences,function(sentence){
    sentence=gsub('[[:punct:]]','', sentence)
    sentence=gsub('[[:cntrl:]]','', sentence)
    sentence=gsub('\\d+','', sentence)
    sentence=tolower(sentence)
    words<- strsplit(sentence, "\\s+")[[1]]
    New=NULL
    for(i in 1:length(words)-1){ 
      New[i]=paste(words[i],words[i+1])     
   }
New=as.matrix(New)
colnames(New)<-"Bigrams"
New
})
merge(bigrams2,all=TRUE)

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but you might find it simpler to use the built-in functionality of `tm` and `RWeka` for this:

```
library(RWeka)   # for NGramTokenizer(...)
library(tm)
# sample data
data <- data.frame(text=c("This is some text.",
                          "This is some other text.",
                          "This is some punctuation; and some more, and more...",
                          "These are some numbers: 1,2,3,4, five."))

doc  <- PlainTextDocument(data$text)
doc  <- removeNumbers(doc)
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(doc)), 
                          control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
result <- rownames(tdm)
result
#  [1] "and more"         "and some"         "are some"         "is some"         
#  [5] "more and"         "numbers five"     "other text"       "punctuation and" 
#  [9] "some more"        "some numbers"     "some other"       "some punctuation"
# [13] "some text"        "these are"        "this is"
```

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment.

So here is a method that doesn't use the `NGramTokenizer` in `RWeka`. The uses a modified version of the `bigrams(...)` function [here](https://gist.github.com/corynissen/8935664). Note that you have to explicitly remove punctuation.

```
bigrams <- function(text){
  word.vec <- strsplit(text, "\\s+")[[1]]
  sapply(1:(length(word.vec)-1), function(x)paste(word.vec[x], word.vec[x+1]))
}
doc  <- PlainTextDocument(data$text)
doc  <- removeNumbers(doc)
doc  <- removePunctuation(doc)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(doc)), 
                          control = list(tokenize = bigrams))
result.2 <- rownames(tdm)

identical(result,result.2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I saw some people doing this online, however, I cannot get RWeka to work on my computer.  Do you know why this would be?  This is the error message I get:Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’

Comment: See my edits for a method that does not use `RWeka`. As far as installing this package, my advice would be to make sure you have the latest version of R and the latest version of the Java runtime installed first. It looks like the install program can't find the Java runtime at all on your system??